# ReActiveAndroid - Database info referenced not found

Tags: android, database, orm, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I want replace old DB codes with [ReActiveAndroid](https://imangazalievm.gitbooks.io/reactiveandroid/) But there is an error for all operations

As mentioned in document, i have these classes :

**Database Class**

```
@Database(name = "MyDatabase", version = 1)
public class MyDatabase {
}
```

**Application Class**

```
DatabaseConfig appDatabase = new DatabaseConfig.Builder(MyDatabase.class)
            .build();

ReActiveAndroid.init(new ReActiveConfig.Builder(this)
            .addDatabaseConfigs(appDatabase)
            .build());
```

**Model Class**

```
@Table(database = MyDatabase.class)
public class User extends Model {
    ...
}
```

**Insert Code**

```
User user = new User();
user.id = id;
user.name = name;
user.save();
```

I have this error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database info referenced with table ir.hatamiarash.app.models.User not found

Are there any settings I've missed?

Comment: Having the same problem, did you figure it out?

Comment: @nasch It's an old library and i couldn't solve this problem... Try to use another one like Realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, but the reason I chose ReactiveAndroid is to migrate from ActiveAndroid.  Realm doesn't use SQLite which means the migration process would be more involved.

I found how to fix this problem:

`DatabaseConfig appDatabase = new DatabaseConfig.Builder(AppDatabase.class)
                        .addModelClasses(LogEntry.class)
                        .addMigrations(AppDatabase.MIGRATION_16_17)
                        .build();`

You have to call `addModelClasses`.  There is also some documentation that helped with subsequent errors that cropped up: https://imangazalievm.gitbooks.io/reactiveandroid/migration-from-activeandroid.html